# If a certain attribute is updated to true, then run method that updates another attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, callback

The claass User has the attributes `activated: boolean` and `activated_at: date_time`.

When the attribute `activated` gets set to the value `true` I want to automatically run a method that runs a couple of conditionals and then sets the attribute `activated_at` to the current date and time.

I tried to set an `after_update :set_activated_at, if: :activated_changed?` callback that updates `activated_at` if `activated` equals to `true`, but that of course creates an eternal loop.

What would be the best way to run a method to update an attribute if another attribute equals to a certain value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, really!

```
after_update :set_activated_at

def set_activated_at
  if activated_changed? && activated == true
  update_column(:activated_at, Time.now)
end
```